# Should I calculate a resistor value for driving indicator LEDs from TTL outputs?

Tags: led, current, ttl

Traditionally I have always used a \$1\:\mathrm{k\Omega}\$ resistor as a current limiting resistor for driving an LED direct from a TTL (or 5V CMOS) output.  I can't remember how I came by this value - it is lost in the annals of history.

Is this OK, or a Bad Habit™ I have got myself into that I should break?

Should I be calculating a more precise resistance to use from the voltage and current draw of the LED I am using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a Bad Habit, just like thoughtlessly using a 1k\$\Omega\$ base resistor for a switching transistor, or as thoughtlessly using a 100nF decoupling capacitor. Millions of engineers get away with it.

Even without much calculation we can see that 1k\$\Omega\$ is a bad choice. From a +5V supply it won't allow more than 5mA, and that's even without taking the LED's voltage drop into account.

Everything depends on the LED, specifically the color, which determines the **forward voltage**. Also, what **current** does it need? An often used value is 20mA, because above that the brightness won't increase so much anymore. Let's take that value, and a forward voltage of 2V.

I also presume that by TTL you mean Low-Power Schottky, the original TTL is really obsolete. OK, we take the datasheet for a [typical LS-TTL part](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls00.pdf). The TI datasheets are interesting, because they give you a complete schematic of a gate. We're mainly interested in the output stage. First thing you see is that the **totem-pole** output (as it's called) is asymmetric: the transistor to \$V_{CC}\$ has a resistor in series with the collector, which the lower transistor doesn't have. This is typical of (LS-)TTL, and means that it will *sink more current than it will source*. How much? That we find on page 5.

> High-level output current: **-0.4mA**,
>   Low-level output current: **8mA**.

The 0.4mA is much too low to drive a LED, but also the 8mA is a bit low. **Standard totem-pole LS-TTL is not fit for driving LEDs.**
The good news is that there are other output configurations. The [74LS06](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ds/sdls020e/sdls020e.pdf) has an **open-collector** output, which means it can only sink current. The datasheet says

> Low-level output current: **40mA**.

Great, that's what we want.

So now we have a device which can drive our LED, we calculate the resistor. There's one more thing we need from the datasheet, that's \$V_{OL}\$, the output voltage when low. Datasheet doesn't say for 20mA, so we interpolate a bit and say 0.5V. Then

> \$R = \dfrac{5V - 2V - 0.5V}{20 mA} = 125\Omega\$

Take the closest E12 value, that's 120\$\Omega\$. A value of 1k\$\Omega\$ was probably alright for the TTL port, but didn't result in optimal LED brightness.

**edit**
Kevin added CMOS to the question. HCMOS is the most used series here. Unlike TTL CMOS outputs are symmetrical, and they can sink current as well as source. The [74HC00](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT00.pdf) can both source and sink 25mA, so we can use it to drive our typical indicator LED.

Comment: Mostly I am driving from a PIC's I/O port, which can drive or sink 25mA on a pin.  Strictly speaking I guess it's CMOS not TTL I'm working with, but \$V_{DD}\$ is 5V, so I just work as if it were TTL

Comment: @Matt - Matt, man what are you doing to me! Let me dig up those datasheets, a whole song and dance about TTL, and in the end it's HCMOS! :-). Well, at least now you know 1)how to calculate it, and 2)to read datasheets.

Comment: Heh, sorry mate ;)  Anyway, I do sometimes want to drive an LED from a 74LS device, so now I know to buffer it first.  Btw - I could use a transistor to buffer it, yes?

Comment: @Matt - sure. Remember that the source capability is limited to 0.4mA, but most low-power switching transistors will have an \$H_{FE}\$ more than 100, so that should be OK. To calculate the base resistor: check datasheet to see what the output voltage is when sourcing 0.4mA, and subtract from that the 0.6V base-emitter voltage, and divide by the 0.4mA (or whatever current you need)

Comment: I would say it is a time-effective habit. When your LED illuminates sufficiently 1k is a fine first order guess. In most situations it won't even destroy a 2mA LED.

Comment: @Wouter - I don't agree. If you pick a 1k\$\Omega\$ and notice it lights very dim, what do you do? Pick a 100\$\Omega\$, and unknowingly use the gate out of spec. Reading the datasheet and making the calculation won't take hours, and you'll become **experienced**, so that you **know** the right value by heart.

Comment: @stevenh - if 1k lights the LED very dim it is of course stupid to pick a 100R without doing a calculation. Let's do one: 5.5V (maximum 7805 output, assuming that's the power source) - 2V (sorta minimal LED drop) - 0.5V (sorta minimal driver drop) / 100R = 30 mA. So (assuming your grab box has only 20mA LEDs) even 150R is a safe value. It's a pity that most chips do not specify a *minimal* driver drop, so a calculation like this is always a bit shaky.