# Am I using this multiplexer (SN74LS153N) correctly?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-analysis, multiplexer, attiny

I'm trying to make an ATtiny85 control an SN74LS153N dual 4-to-1 multiplexer in order to read state of several switches using a single pin (three pins actually), but am having trouble understanding why my design does not work.

[image]

This is what my prototype looks like at the moment. The LEDs are there only to explain my issue.

No matter what state the switches S1 to S4 are in D3 never lights up and U2  never seems to be able to read the digital state of PB4 input. U2 is programmed to iterate through all states of A and B inputs to U1 and that is what it does: D1 and D2 flash accordingly - OFF:OFF, OFF:ON, ON:OFF, ON:ON (D1:D2).

I've read the datasheets over and over and checked and verified that everything is hooked up as required. Am I missing something obvious? Are those switches to blame?

[SN74LS153N](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54153.pdf)

[ATtiny85](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2586-avr-8-bit-microcontroller-attiny25-attiny45-attiny85_datasheet.pdf)

Comment: Have you tried adding a series resistor of, say 330 Ω, to each of the LEDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The clearest problem is that U1 pin 1 (`1G`) is unconnected, and so it will typically float `HIGH` on TTL devices.

  That means that U1 pin 7 (`1Y`) will stay `LOW`, *irrespective* of the states on the inputs U1 pins 3 - 6 (`1C3` to `1C0`).

  See the first line of the truth table, in the datasheet which you kindly linked:

[image: 74LS153N truth table]

- I understand that they are just for troubleshooting, but that U1 LS TTL outputs don't have enough *source* current to drive an LED (i.e. with the LED between a U1 output and `Gnd`) and stay within spec. The datasheet says the recommended maximum source current is just 0.8 mA (800 μA).

  Better to use a transistor (BJT or MOSFET) driver, to avoid damaging the U1 outputs and to still get a valid `HIGH` logic level for U2 to read.

  This [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16281/should-i-calculate-a-resistor-value-for-driving-indicator-leds-from-ttl-outputs) explains the problem.
- Finally, you should have decoupling capacitors close to U1 and U2.

  You *might* get away without them, but that would depend on several factors and best practice is to include them.

---

This short Fairchild "[Designing with TTL](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/application-notes/AN/AN-363.pdf)" Application Note 363) has some useful advice on various topics, including decoupling and what to do with unused TTL inputs.

Comment: Apparently I don't know how to read truth tables. I was under the impression that strobe was an irrelevant output in my case, since it only seems to be relevant when connecting multiple SN74LS153N ICs together (remember reading that somewehere). Yet the results are obvious. After I pull strobe low, multitool readings are consistent with what I expected (I've removed the LEDs).

Comment: @predi - Hi - Glad you've confirmed the problem :-) "I was under the impression that strobe was an irrelevant output in my case". Actually "Strobe" (signal `1G`on the part of the LS153 you are using) is an *input*, and so it must be considered. Look at the logic diagram on the lower half of page 2 of the LS153 datasheet, where it shows that "Strobe" signal is an input to the internal `AND` gates. P.S. Best practice would be to connect the inputs on the second-half of the LS153 device too. I will add a link in my answer to a TTL design application note, with some info. Good luck!

Comment: The actual prototype is already using both MUXes in the IC (8 switches). Thanks for all the suggestions. I'm now reading on decoupling capacitors and will add them. This was (and still is) a learning experience. :)