# 8-bit shift register 74LS164 not working

Tags: raspberry-pi, ttl, register

I am trying to use an SN74LS164 8-bit serial-to-parallel shift register with my Raspberry Pi, but I have some problems.

I connected:

- VCC, A, B and CLR to +5V
- GND to 0V
- CLK to Raspberry Pi GPIO

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZdUYy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When I power-on the circuit, all the LEDs are off. Then I send a clock pulse from the Raspberry Pi (go high for 100ms then go low). However instead of having the just first output (QA) go high, the first 3 or 4 outputs go high (QA, QB, QC and QD).

What am I doing wrong?

I took some photos of the scope, the first is the clock from the GPIO (without nothing) and the second is the clock connected to the register.

[image: Clock only]

[image: Clock connected to register]

**-- EDIT --**

I added capacitors and MOSFETs to respect max output current. I re-added pull-down resitor on clock line because of the natural +1V offset (this offset come from the register not the pi)

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope? You are probably getting multiple pulses instead of just one. Or, the pulse has a ragged edge(s) and the 164 is actually clocking several times. You should use a 74HCT164 instead of the LS version. You might simply have a logic level compatibility issue between Pi and the LS164 inputs.

Comment: Might be missing decoupling capacitors too.

Comment: @FiddyOhm Reading the datasheet here, I can't find an issue with the logic levels. The thresholds are 0.8 and 2 volts, and it shouldn't draw enough current to sink the raspberry pi's output, even if it's just 3.3 volts.

Comment: What happens if you pulse the clock line a second time? Also, is it always the exact same behavior?

Comment: @JamesMagnus - (a) Please confirm that I have correctly interpreted what is actually happening during your test, in my edit of your question (i.e. 3 or 4 LEDs (QA-QC or QA-QD) turn on, instead of only 1 (QA) which is expected). (b) Why do you have R9 (5k pull-down) on the CLK pin? Unless you have a clear justification for that resistor (if so, please explain), remove that resistor and retry your test.

Comment: @JamesMagnus - (c) Although this *might* not be causing your problem, your circuit has the LS164 *sourcing* current to the LEDs, targeting up to (5V-2V LED drop)/300 Ohm = 10mA per LED (though VOH will drop, also reducing the LED current). Look in the LS164 datasheet & notice recommended max IOH = 0.4mA (400uA), which is typical for totem-pole LS TTL outputs. See this [answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/16283) to a previous topic, for more info. Better to use 1k resistors & use the LS164 to *sink* the LED current (i.e. connect the LEDs + resistors between the outputs and 5V rail).

Comment: @SamGibson I add the pull down resistor because I though the clock signal wasn't at 0V when low. But this didn't solve my problem. Tomorrow I will find an oscilloscope to look clock signal

Comment: If the clock is dirty, can I use a Schmitt trigger to have a better one?

Comment: @TomBrendlinger If I pulse the clock a second time I have 7 or the 8 led turned on (expected 2: QA and QB). It's really like there are multiple clock pulses in one

Comment: @JamesMagnus - "add[ed] the pull down resistor because I though[t] the clock signal wasn't at 0V when low. But this didn't solve my problem" - I'm not surprised. That resistor should not be needed; problem is elsewhere. Need some real measurements before I can advise further. Pictures from your 'scope with the GPIO signal (i) disconnected from LS164 CLK and (ii) connected to LS164 CLK, are needed (use edit button and add them to the bottom of your original question). I assume the RPi 0V rail is connected to your LS164 0V rail? Also *add decoupling cap* at the LS164 as Transistor said.

Comment: I think I might agree with @Transistor here- try adding a capacitor. This image might make the possible problem clear: https://en-us.knowledgebase.renesas.com/@api/deki/files/1223/=edge3.gif?revision=1&size=bestfit&width=531&height=270

Comment: @SamGibson Yes all GND are connected together, I will measure with the scope after work.

Comment: James: The scope pictures are good. Do you see that little crick in the negative edge of the waveform? Expand the trace in the horizontal direction by going to a faster sweep time and get a finer grain picture of that falling edge and the crick. Remember, the 164 clocks on the negative edge of the clock pulse, that edge should be nice & straight and as fast as possible. It looks like you have the scope in AUTO trigger mode. You want to have it in NORMAL trigger mode to get a good trace of the negative edge.

Comment: @FiddyOhm: I add a capacitor (100 pF) between clock and ground, I reduce the duty cycle of clock (it's written < 50% in the datasheet). Now the clock is very very clean on the scope and it works for 1 or 2 pulses. If I try 3 pulses there are 3 more leds (5 in total) turned on. So the mystery stays full. I think this chip is too sensitive.

Comment: Furthermore, are you sure the register clocks on the faling edge? Datasheet says rising edge. [link](http://www.ti.com/product/SN74LS164/technicaldocuments)

Comment: You have to zoom in to expand the edges. The device can be clocked up to 36MHz, so you'll have to zoom in to the 10ns range to get a good picture. Also, you said the device was being operated at 5V, but the scope appears to show something smaller, if I'm reading right.

Comment: @kjgregory Yes it's 3V because it's from the pi GPIO

Comment: The second scope picture looks like a 3.3V signal with GND around 1V. It definitely won't work correctly if your negative going pulse doesn't pass through ~0.8V or so.

Comment: @David: there is 1V offset on the clock because the register clock pin is at ~1V constantly

Comment: Why is there a 1v offset?

Comment: I don't know why there is an offset, if I connect Vcc and GND only, the CLK pin is at +1V

Comment: You have an unexplained 1V offset.  Perhaps this has something to do with your problem.  Finding out where that offset comes from should be the absolute first priority here.

Comment: @JamesMagnus - While I've been away, I see *Scott* has kindly been focussing effort on that abnormal offset on the LS164 CLK signal which we started to discuss yesterday. Therefore I won't re-enter the discussion and "muddy the waters" with additional, but potentially different, troubleshooting steps :-) I would certainly follow his suggestion to disconnect all LEDs and re-test using 'scope to check LS164 outputs (leave all LS164 inputs connected - also measure CLK signal voltage when driven low by RPi, before pulse from RPi with LEDs disconnected, to see if 1V offset still exists). Good luck!

Comment: @SamGibson - The 1V offset exists on the register clock input pin as soon as Vcc and GND are connected. So I added a pulldown resistor, now when clock is low, voltage is 0V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem. The register was clocking multiple times because the clock signal wasn't enough clean. So I added a schmitt trigger between the raspberry pi and the register clock input, and now it shifts exactly the number I want.

Thanks for all your advices and suggestions, have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 1):

A Low power Schottky input typically sits at about 1.3V when open circuit, and sources ~0.25mA when pulled low (<0.8V). The Pi should have no trouble driving this load, but in your case it only managed to pull the clock input down to ~1.1V.

You got it down to 0V with a pull-down resistor, which suggests that the LS164's input is OK and your Pi's GPIO line is *not* pulling down properly. Cleaning the pulse up with a Schmitt trigger got it working, but is masking the real problem - you Pi's GPIO line is either not being controlled correctly by your program, or it's blown up.

Comment: I know there is a pull down and a pull up in the raspberry pi when you configure the GPIO as input, but is there a pull down when you are in output mode?

Comment: Output mode is push-pull with at least 2mA sink capability. https://www.scribd.com/doc/101830961/GPIO-Pads-Control2

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at the [data sheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls164.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiFr8_S163OAhVOziYKHaF8AbcQFggeMAE&usg=AFQjCNGHzqE1Wx0XLJ-To2i4rutVC4UmXA&sig2=8m8XSL3jkgMd2Xi2l0OAKw).  This chip can't drive the kind of current you want it to.  Thus exceeding operating conditions, all bets are off.

Comment: I use leds to see what happen. In real I will put mosfets to control a (big) led board. 

In the datasheet it's -400 µA so should the voltage be negative at the ouputs?

Comment: Negative seems to indicate source current, and positive sink current.  You should test with the FETs in place.

Comment: Ok I m going to try with the FETs to respect the output current

Comment: You might even need to replace the shift register, but probably not.

Comment: Better yet, @JamesMagnus, you have a scope.  Just disconnect the LEDs and use the scope to check outputs.  You haven't shown code, so we're tang you're word that your clock is one pulse at a time, but you should certainly verify that you're not clocking more than once

Answer (score -1):

You likely have reflections on your clock line, causing it to be treated as multiple clock pulses. The length of your clock wire might be a factor in this. If your wires are already short, then consider adding a signal integrity resistor (20-50 ohms) in series with the clock pin (as close to the driver as possible).

Comment: That's a good guess, but the recent oscilloscope pictures (posted after your answer) looks pretty clean.

Comment: That's pretty far fetched, given the frequencies involved.

Comment: Looks pretty clean but you need to zoom way in to know for sure. Also, why does the scope only show 2Vpp in one picture?

Comment: The measurement (or what I think is the measurement) number in all the screen shots says 3.3 v.  Have you ever had bounce problems using a simple microcontroller DIO, especially at low freq?  Hasn't ever happened to me.  When the asker is sourcing more than the chip can do by more than a factor of 10, I'd look there first.